# why doesn't a struct conform to Equatable when only its only property conforms to an Equatable protocol?

Tags: swift

Compiler provides error message `Type 'A' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable''`

Why? The extension on the `Accessible` protocol should provides Equatable conformance, no?

```
struct A: Equatable {
    var simp: any Accessible
}


protocol Accessible: Equatable {
    var accessToken: String {get set}
}

extension Accessible {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.accessToken == rhs.accessToken}
}
```

Comment: Because Accessible is a protocol, not a real type, and protocols cannot conform to themselves?

Comment: The property does not conform to Equatable. `any Accessible` does not itself conform to `Accessible`, and also does not conform to `Equatable`. Protocols do not conform to themselves (protocols never conform to protocols; they only can require other protocols). The Equatable protocol requires that two items of the same concrete type (not a protocol) have an `==`.

Comment: While it's a bit of head-scratcher, maybe the easiest way for me to internalize it is simply that one protocol can't conform to another. I won't ask why.  If that's the case, shouldn't it be easy enough for the compiler to detect that invalid construction, and throw an error?

Comment: It does.  It's the error you've put in the question...